# Warning: match nonexhaustive - handling a specific case (SML)

Tags: sml

Consider the following example of a list in SML: `[[("foo",~10.0)],[("goo",~8.0)]]`.

I would link to write a function which will delete the main brackets meaning the output will be:

`[("foo", ~10.0), ("goo, ~8.0)]`

The function I wrote:

```
fun inner_list [[]] = [] | inner_list [] = [] 
|  inner_list ((((x:(string*real))::xt)::xs)) = x :: inner_list xs;
```

It works for most cases but I know that I didn't check one of the cases. I think this case is:

`[[],("foo", ~10.0)]`

I know that I didn't handle one of the cases because the compiler alerts:

```
stdIn:1.6-2.68 Warning: match nonexhaustive
      nil :: nil => ...
      nil => ...
      (x :: xt) :: xs => ...
```

I read other articles related with the `Warning: match nonexhaustive` warning, but I didn't understand how to solve it with my program.

How to handle the other case?

**EDIT** I know that my list contains only one list. this is why I don't use `xt`

Comment: How come you don't do anything with `xt`?

Comment: @sepp2k because I know that there is only one list in a list. Ill edit my description

Comment: You need to decide how you want to handle that case. Should you fail, or just leave that element out, or something else?

Comment: `[[],("foo", ~10.0)]` isn't a valid case since that expression is ill-typed.

Comment: @molbdnilo I would like it to return the sublist without the `nil` list. `[[],("foo", ~10.0)]` will return [("foo", ~10.0)]

Comment: @vesii That case is `inner_list ([]::xs)`. (This also covers the `[[]]` case.)

Comment: @versii yes thank you that's handels with my problem. don't know didn't I think of it..

Comment: A simple way of doing what you intend to do is `fun inner_list xss = map hd xss`

Answer (score 1):

How about the built-in `List.concat`?

```
List.concat [[("foo",~10.0)], [("goo",~8.0)]] =
    [("foo",~10.0), ("goo",~8.0)]
```